# How to apply code to all the files in a directly and convert xml files to txt files

Tags: python, loops, operating-system, elementtree, xmlconvert

I'm trying to apply code in python to extract necessary information from each xml file and write them in txt files.
I successfully executed my code but the result shows only one file.
Also, my code doesn't look smart, I would be very glad if anyone can help me to solve the problem and give me some correction.

I'm afraid I'm very beginner so I might have many fundamental mistakes...

here is my code

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import os

path = r'/Users/mo/Documents/annotations/xmls'
filenames = []

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if not filename.endswith('.xml'):
        continue
    fullname = os.path.join(path,filename)
    filenames.append(fullname)

each_name = filename[:-4]

with open(each_name + '.txt', 'a') as f:

    for filename in filenames:
        tree = ET.parse(filename)
        root = tree.getroot()

        for object in root.findall('object'):
            categoryID = object.find('name').text

            for bnd_box in object.findall('bndbox'):
                Xcenter = (int(bnd_box.find('xmax').text) - int(bnd_box.find('xmin').text))/2
                Ycenter = (int(bnd_box.find('ymax').text) - int(bnd_box.find('ymin').text))/2
                width = int(bnd_box.find('xmax').text)- int(bnd_box.find('xmin').text)
                height = int(bnd_box.find('ymax').text) - int(bnd_box.find('ymin').text)
                Detection_rows = str(categoryID) + str(Xcenter) + str(Ycenter) + str(width) + str(height) + '\n'

    f.write(str(Detection_rows))
```

Thank you very much

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong just by a quick glance at the code. Can you tell us __exactly__ why this isn't working for you?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, IT IS kind of working, but in the destination file only one file was created, but I wanted to have more because I have more than 2000 xml files in original folder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (**did not test it**)

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import os

path = r'/Users/mo/Documents/annotations/xmls'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if not filename.endswith('.xml'):
        continue
        
    fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)

    with open(fullname[:-4] + '.txt', 'a') as f:

        tree = ET.parse(fullname)
        root = tree.getroot()

        for object in root.findall('object'):
            categoryID = object.find('name').text

            for bnd_box in object.findall('bndbox'):
                Xcenter = (int(bnd_box.find('xmax').text) - int(bnd_box.find('xmin').text))/2
                Ycenter = (int(bnd_box.find('ymax').text) - int(bnd_box.find('ymin').text))/2
                width = int(bnd_box.find('xmax').text)- int(bnd_box.find('xmin').text)
                height = int(bnd_box.find('ymax').text) - int(bnd_box.find('ymin').text)
                Detection_rows = str(categoryID) + str(Xcenter) + str(Ycenter) + str(width) + str(height) + '\n'

        f.write(str(Detection_rows))
```

Your for loop should be outside the `open` and you changed `filenames` for `filename`. Also, I removed one unnecessary for loop. Let me know if it solves the issue for you.

Comment: oh Thank you very very much for your quick answer! I'll try it now and get it back here !